# Windows RT get username in domain

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

Developing a windows store app and I want to get the current windows user in the app.

```
string username = await UserInformation.GetDisplayNameAsync();
```

Works perfectly but when the computer is in domain it returns an empty string, how can I get the display name when a computer is in a domain ?

Comment: I found a solution to the problem. In the Privacy Settings of windows for the current machine the permissions to get user information were off. Cheers!